# Convert assembly to hexadecimal. How do to this step by step?

Tags: assembly, hex

I have this question:

> Provide the type and hexadecimal representation of following instruction: sw $t1, 32($t2)

So I have this in binary:

101011   01010    01001    0000 0000 0010 0000

43        10        9           32

43 is the op code for store word and .
10 is the register code for $t2
9 is the register code for $t1 .
32 is the address

But how do I then convert this to hexadecimal?

Comment: You need to specify the architecture. Without it, no one can tell you which bits and bytes will map to a specific instruction or vice versa.

Comment: Group the binary digits into clumps of 4.  You'll have 8 clumps: each is one hex digit.

Comment: What you're asking for is an assembler. An assembler takes assembly instructions and produces the binary data output. While a disassembler takes the binary and produces the assembly representation. As mentioned this is completely dependant on the architecutre.

Comment: Oh I see... so I'm grouping them because I'm assuming it's an R-type instruction?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you're running this on MIPS32 architecture. The instructions do produce the binary output you wrote but your decimal representation of the output is incorrect. If the first eight bits produce 32 which is accurate then the next eight bits can not produce a 9. And in some areas you've grouped five bits as apposed to four bits. So the first step would be to group them correctly.

1010 1101 0100 1001 0000 0000 0010 0000

Now the first eight bits produce 32.

The next eight bits produce 0.

The next eight bits produce 73.

And the last eight bits produce 173.

Now you just need the hex representation of each decimal value.

32 in Hex is 20.

0 in Hex is 0.

73 in Hex is 49.

173 in Hex is ad.

Which in Little Endian leaves you with the instruction as

20 00 49 ad

In your case either your binary represetation of the assembly instruction is wrong or your decimal representation of the binary representation is wrong. If you are using MIP32 architecture then your binary is accurate but your decimal is inaccurate.

Comment: It's true, that the sw-opcode (binary 101011) comes from the MIPS instruction set. But before the hexadecimal representation “20 00 49 ad” can be executed on the machine, a special markup is needed. In the Forth language, the Hex word allows to represent hexadecimal values. It can be combined with the word “code” for storing assembly opcodes direct into the sourcecode.

Comment: K is the symbol for potassium

Comment: The main problem with assembly language is, that it's not a universal language which runs on all machines, but it depends heavily on the underlying hardware. Using Forth as a high level assembler makes things more easier to understand and is especially useful for converting mnemonic opcodes into hexadecimal one.